# How To Apply REPLACE and UPPER Simultaneously On One Column In SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, uppercase

I would like to remove any white spaces in my `id` column and capitalize it simultaneously. The below code gives me a separate column where one is the removed white spaces and the other is the capitalized. Is it possible to apply both `REPLACE` and `UPPER` so that the output is one column instead of two ?

```
SELECT REPLACE(id, ' ', ''), UPPER(id) FROM db
```

Comment: Try `UPPER(REPLACE(id, ' ', ''))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call one on the result of the other:

```sql
SELECT UPPER(REPLACE(id, ' ', '')) FROM db
```